# MongoDB Query Nested Schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have the next schemas:

Product Schema:

```
_id: String
name: String
description: String
company: Company
```

Company Schema:

```
_id: String
name: string
```

I'm trying to find all the products that match my query string with the name or company name.

I already tried:

```
const query: any[] = [
  {
    "company.name": {
      $regex: name,
      $options: "i",
    },
  },
  {
    "name": {
      $regex: name,
      $options: "i",
    },
  }
];

return Product.find()
  .or(query)
  .populate("company")
```

Data - Products:

```
{ _id: "6067b7d7b5913759d9bb8b39", "name": "Test 1", "description": "Desc", "company": "6067b809c78a4a39ebeae4d4" }
```

Data - Companies:

```
{ _id: "6067b809c78a4a39ebeae4d4", "name": "Facebook" }, 
{ _id: "59862209c78a4a39ebeae4d4", "name": "Apple" },
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will filter only products, will not work in your case as you want to filter by `company.name` also

```
Product.find()
  .or(query)
  .populate("company")
```

---

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/VqREj1vvkss

Use aggregation query to achieve this

```
db.companies.aggregate([
  { $lookup: { "from": "products", "localField": "_id",  "foreignField": "company",  "as": "products"} },
  { $unwind: "$products" },
  { $match: {
    $or: [
        { "name": { $regex: "Test 1",$options: "i", }, },
        { "products.name": { $regex: "Test 1",$options: "i" } }
    ]}
  }
])
```

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html#aggregate_Aggregate